# Client-sided password generator (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, passwords, generator

I've stumbled upon a desktop project (in particular an executable program) that is generating random strings of data constantly/repetitively/continuously. Here is a preview of it below:

[image]

However, I'd like to code that within Javascript. Since the idea is pretty perplex, I cannot simply start from nothing and was hoping if anybody here has developed something similar or has any notion as to how I could go about doing this in Javascript to give me some information or other resources, maybe jQuery plugins or whatever.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SO isn't really for helping this early in the development process. But, you can find the source code online as [`passgen`](https://github.com/defuse/passgen) (CLI) and [`WinPassGen`](https://github.com/defuse/WinPassGen) (GUI), as well as a [PHP port](https://github.com/defuse/php-passgen).

Comment: The PHP source is not working for me. Could you run it on your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look particularly hard, except that Javascript's `Math.random` is not a high-quality source of random numbers.  You might look at some of the recently released implementations of the **[Web Cryptography API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#dfn-RandomSource-method-getRandomValues)** for ideas of how to improve on that.

Once you have that, converting the stream of random numbers into the different formats should be straightforward, and using mouse movements to add entropy should also not be difficult.

Which parts strike you as particularly difficult?

**Update**:

I posted a partial version on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/qCfLh/)**.  This just shows how the field is continually updated and frozen.  But it doesn't do anything with cryptography.  You would still need to convert mouse movements into a set of numeric values to serve as inputs into a more robust random number generator.  But converting mouse movements into numbers is pretty simple.  Again, do look at the **[Web Cryptography API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#dfn-RandomSource-method-getRandomValues)** for more information.

It uses these snippets:

```
var getRandomHexDigit = function() {
    return (Math.floor(16 * Math.random())).toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
```

and

```
setInterval(function() {
    hex.value = hex.value.substring(1) + getRandomHexDigit();
}, 50);
```

Comment: The moving part of the generations specifically. The effect of their exit from the field and the 'arrival' of the next string that had been generated.

Comment: @JoshGreenary: I don't know if my update offers any help with your problems.  (It's not clear to me what you mean by "the moving part of hte generations".)  Does this at least start you in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, it completely satisfies my curiosity! Thank you for your time :)